# How to export partial Cassandra table data to another Cassandra db?

Tags: cassandra

I have a special request that I have to export partial table's data to another Cassandra db. Two servers are in different data center in different country.

The exported table is the same structure as original, only the new db is the subset of the old one.

For example, the table has 3 column [user, cxtId, cxt], and the [user, cxtId] is the primary key.

In general case, I will have a user with many cxtId. Assume I have ten user's data in db now, but I only want to export 3 of them into the new db, the target may has some data with the same primary key exist and I want overwrite that data.

How can I do this in Cassandra.

I have checked the COPY command, but it seems support full data set ( may with partial columns).

Are there good approach to achieve my problem? Thank you.

Eric

Comment: try spark cassandra connector

Comment: you can scp sstables to other datacenter and run sstableloader

Comment: If you want to only copy a subset of the data you'll need to write a tool to do this yourself (e.g. with the python driver): query the rows/partitions that you need from cluster1 and insert them into cluster2.

Comment: Hi undefined_variable, does spark Cassandra connector mean I have to write program by my self, or it have a tool can help me to do my task? I already have some codes to access my Cassandra, just want to find some way that easier and more standard to import/export Cassandra. It would be better to met this request through a common tool.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a tool from GitHub can solve my problem.
https://github.com/gianlucaborello/cassandradump

I can use this python script to dump selected result and use cqlsh -f to load data back to Cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

I used one library into my project that helped me transform the huge amount of data from one table to another.

I think you can explore this library from here..
https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-loader

You unload the data, manipulate if you want and load the data to the new table..